# powershell Script that only writes certain Parts from the cmd interface to a .txt file

Tags: windows, powershell, text-files

I am new to PowerShell and am currently working on a script that writes the result of the `wbadmin get versions` command into a text file. The result contains two (or more) entries.

**My Result (in german):**

```
wbadmin 1.0 - Sicherungs-Befehlszeilentool
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 10:02 
Sicherungsziel: 1394/USB-Datenträger, Beschriftung Volume Ni-ssan Skyline(D:)
Versions-ID: 01/06/2022-09:02
Wiederherstellbar: Volume(s), Datei(en), Anwendung(en), Bare-Metal-Recovery, Systemstatus
Snapshot-ID: {a14340c6-b013-4f24-9e0c-01b508d32e73}

Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 15:43 
Sicherungsziel: 1394/USB-Datenträger, Beschriftung Volume Ni-ssan Skyline(D:)
Versions-ID: 01/06/2022-14:43
Wiederherstellbar: Volume(s), Datei(en), Anwendung(en), Bare-Metal-Recovery, Systemstatus
Snapshot-ID: {eaac6691-2fc7-416c-aec2-b9c936908206}
```

**Script for testing:**

```
$patht = "C:\blaBla.txt"
$process = wbadmin get versions

New-Item $patht
Add-Content $patht -Value $Process
```

The problem is that I'm only interested in the second (*06.01.2022 15:43*) entry. Is there a way that only the wanted entry gets exported to my .txt file?

Comment: PowerShell can easily invoke external commands (like `wbadmin`), the difficulty though, is scraping the unstructured output of these commands. Therefore it is recommend use powershell [cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview) (like [`windowsserverbackup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsserverbackup/)) instead.

Comment: @iRon I am trying to create a script that isn't Server-bound, therefore WindowsServerBackup is sadly not possible in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answering my own question)

I dug around a bit more that Day and found probably the easiest solution there is to the problem. I just split the Task up.

**The finished Code:**

```
$patht = "C:\temp\BackUpInfo.txt"
$pathm = "C:\temp\UwU.txt"
$process = wbadmin get versions

#.txt file with webadmin result#
New-Item $pathm
Add-Content $pathm -Value $process 

#seperate newest log entry#
$last = Get-Content $pathm
$akt = $last | Select-Object -Last 6

#.txt file with newest log#
New-Item $patht
Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\BackUpInfo.txt" -Value $akt
```

So, let's break it down... First I created a .txt file where I save my *"wbadmin"* result.

After that, I looked at the exported .txt and noticed that the latest Backup is always the lowest one. I then counted how many lines contain said entry. So I just separated the wanted lines into a variable.

Last but not least I then created my final .txt file to which I exported my previously separated log entry. And after that, I had my wanted result. There's probably a better solution to this, but this works flawlessly and that's enough to satisfy me. Later on in my Script both of these files get deleted after *"Backupinfo"* got attached to an E-Mail, so there is never any Error along the lines of *"this file already exist"*. So yeah... a pretty simple solution to a simple problem.

-Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> I'm only interested in the second (06.01.2022 15:43) entry.

I suppose you mean you're only interested in the final entry of the list, not the entry with that particular date.

You can split at a double newline and take the last part:

```
$process = @"
wbadmin 1.0 - Sicherungs-Befehlszeilentool
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 10:02 
Sicherungsziel: 1394/USB-Datenträger, Beschriftung Volume Ni-ssan Skyline(D:)
Versions-ID: 01/06/2022-09:02
Wiederherstellbar: Volume(s), Datei(en), Anwendung(en), Bare-Metal-Recovery, Systemstatus
Snapshot-ID: {a14340c6-b013-4f24-9e0c-01b508d32e73}

Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 15:43 
Sicherungsziel: 1394/USB-Datenträger, Beschriftung Volume Ni-ssan Skyline(D:)
Versions-ID: 01/06/2022-14:43
Wiederherstellbar: Volume(s), Datei(en), Anwendung(en), Bare-Metal-Recovery, Systemstatus
Snapshot-ID: {eaac6691-2fc7-416c-aec2-b9c936908206}
"@

$last = $process -split '\r?\n\r?\n' | select -Last 1
Write-Host $last
```

prints

```
Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 15:43 
Sicherungsziel: 1394/USB-Datenträger, Beschriftung Volume Ni-ssan Skyline(D:)
Versions-ID: 01/06/2022-14:43
Wiederherstellbar: Volume(s), Datei(en), Anwendung(en), Bare-Metal-Recovery, Systemstatus
Snapshot-ID: {eaac6691-2fc7-416c-aec2-b9c936908206}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `wbadmin get versions` returns an array of strings and in that case you can do the following:

```
# join the strings to form a single multilined string
$process = (wbadmin get versions) -join [environment]::NewLine
# split on the empty newlines to get text blocks.
$blocks = $process -split '(\r?\n){2,}' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S'}

# now select the block that has the info for the date you are after
# since the string contains dots (that have special meaning in regex), you need to escape the search string
$search = [regex]::Escape('Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 15:43')
$blocks | Where-Object { $_ -match "(?m)^$search" } | Set-Content -Path "C:\blaBla.txt"
```

Result:

```
Sicherungszeit: 06.01.2022 15:43 
Sicherungsziel: 1394/USB-Datenträger, Beschriftung Volume Ni-ssan Skyline(D:)
Versions-ID: 01/06/2022-14:43
Wiederherstellbar: Volume(s), Datei(en), Anwendung(en), Bare-Metal-Recovery, Systemstatus
Snapshot-ID: {eaac6691-2fc7-416c-aec2-b9c936908206}
```